# canvas.drawRect is black instead of transparent

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I'm trying to draw a glass that's filled with some some sort of soda. I have a `PNG` image for the glass which is quite transparent, and I want to fill a part of it with a color.

here's what I've done so far:

```
glassRect = new Rect(0, 0, 800, 1100);
colorRect = new Rect(0, 800, 800, 1100);



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint imagePaint = new Paint();
    imagePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));


    Paint colorPaint = new Paint();
    colorPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER));
    colorPaint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 160, 85, 45));

    canvas.drawBitmap(glassBitmap, null, glassRect, imagePaint);
    canvas.drawRect(colorRect, colorPaint);
}
```

but that give's me this:
[image]

The part of the glass has turned black instead of staying transparent

How should I solve this? or am I not doing this properly? Let me know please :)

Comment: Can u check with hardware acceleration? check this - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: I'm targetting api 10. Will it work there as well?

Comment: We had above issue in Nexus 7 with 4.2.2, and as that fixed with http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling. You need to check this for API 10.

Comment: Hardware acceleration was not the solution, even when targetting a higher minSdk like 14

Answer (score 0):

Add code below on app's manifest.xml;

```
<application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        ...
</application>
```

Related sentences from the link - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling;

"...If your application uses only standard views and Drawables, turning it on globally should not cause any adverse drawing effects. However, because hardware acceleration is not supported for all of the 2D drawing operations, turning it on might affect some of your custom views or drawing calls."